# recuperar datos de SQL con PHP y convertirlo en JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

Buen dia.

Estimados estoy teniendo inconvenientes al obtener los datos de 1 tabla en SQL SERVER con php y convertirlo en JSON .

Este la parte del código en php:

```
try {
    
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433; Database=$dbname", $user, $password);
 
    $sql = "select * from preguntas";
    // use the connection here
  
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($dbh, $sql);
    // fetch all rows into array, by default PDO::FETCH_BOTH is used

    $result = array();
    
        while($row =sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($result, array(
            'id'=>$row[0],
            'numpregunta'=>$row[1],
            'pregunta'=>$row[2],
            'rutaicoestatus'=>$row[3]));
        }
         echo json_encode($result);
       // echo json_encode(array("data" => array_values($result)));
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
         sqlsrv_close($dbh);
       
      
        
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

Pero al ejecutar por la web se muestra de la siguiente manera vacio :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea en que estoy fallando.

Agregue cierto codigo para verificar que me esta arrojando y obtengo esta información en la web .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y estás seguro que `$results` si tiene valores adentro? Si pones un `var_dump($result); die();` antes de usar `json_encode` si te muestra que tiene elementos adentro?

Comment: De acuerdo voy aplicar esa validación antes de mostrar el json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno estuve investigando y cambie esta linea de codigo y ahora si me arroja el resultado esperado.

```
 try {
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433; Database=$dbname", $user, $password);
       if( $dbh === false ) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                }
    
    // use the connection here
    $stm = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM preguntas');
       if( $stm === false) {
                     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                    }
    // fetch all rows into array, by default PDO::FETCH_BOTH is used
    $rows = $stm->fetchAll();
    $result = array();
    // iterate over array by index and by name
    foreach($rows as $row) {
       // printf("$row[0] $row[1] $row[2]\n");
       // printf($row['id']. $row['numpregunta']. $row['pregunta']."<br />");
            array_push($result, array(
                    'id'=>$row[0],
                    'numpregunta'=>$row[1],
                    'pregunta'=>$row[2]));
    }
    

        
        echo json_encode($result);
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stm);
         sqlsrv_close($dbh);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
```

el resultado es el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]